# Rails Devise timeout redirect immediatly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise timeout table to expire a session, however the redirect only happens after a page refresh or change. What is a good solution to redirect to sign in once the session expires?

Comment: If you want a real time experiencie you could use ActionCable (websockets) and broadcast an expired session message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some client side code to keep track.  If the page is static, you can just do it in javascript:

```
//  Redirect 15 minutes after page loads.
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href="the_new_place"; }, 1000 * 60 * 15);
```

If your page has some user controls and you want to keep the session alive while user is editing something, check out https://github.com/epigenesys/session-timeout-prompter.

ActionCable is another possibility but that's perhaps a little heavy-handed for this purpose.